# How to use Flutter Reactive BLE to send a UUID to a Bluetooth device and save response to string

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been trying to figure out the Flutter Reactive BLE dart library. I have went through the Github example app and got when I want to work. I am wondering if there is an easier way to do what I am doing.

I have tried messing around with the readCharacterisitc but I have had no luck. I don't think I am connecting to the device properly.

```
final characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(serviceId: serviceUuid, characteristicId: characteristicUuid, deviceId: foundDeviceId);
final response = await flutterReactiveBle.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

The goal would be to have all relevant functions and variables to connect to the BLE device in one file so all I have to do is 1 line and get my response for my different UUIDs.

I am also very new to flutter and dart so if I am going about this wrong please let me know.

Comment: Can you make your question more clear?

Comment: I want to be able to connect to a Bluetooth device, send it a UUID, and saved that response to string. 
Basically just have a function that I input the deviceID and the UUID I want to read. And the function outputs the response.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to know the service UUIDs and characteristic UUIDs of that device.

First perform a scan and save the device id.

```
String? deviceId;
final flutterReactiveBle = FlutterReactiveBle();
flutterReactiveBle.scanForDevices(withServices: [serviceId], scanMode: ScanMode.lowLatency).listen((device) {
      //save the device id to a variable
      deviceId = device.id;
    }, onError: () {
      //code for handling error
    });
```

Then use this device id to connect to that device.
You need to know the service ids and characteristic ids of that device.

```
flutterReactiveBle.connectToDevice(
      id: deviceId,
      servicesWithCharacteristicsToDiscover: {serviceId: [charId1, charId2]},
      connectionTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    ).listen((connectionState) {
      if (connectionState.connectionState == DeviceConnectionState.connected) {
        
        // send the data
        final characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(serviceId: serviceUuid, 
        characteristicId: charId1, deviceId: deviceId); 

        var response = await flutterReactiveBle.writeCharacteristicWithResponse(characteristic, value: [0x00]);

      }
    }, onError: (Object error) {
      // Handle a possible error
    });
```

Please note that in many cases, you will get the response on another characteristic UUID. So you will have to listen to that characteristic UUID to get the response.

Comment: I was more so looking for an example on how to do this. But I just have a new function that can do all of this separately. Like this
response = readBluetoothUUID(serviceId, UUID);